# Plotting a histogram using a range of values and their frequency as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

Assume that I have the following dictionary:

```
scenario_summary = {'Day1': {'22459-22585': 0.0, '22585-22711': 0.0, '22711-22837': 0.0, '22837-22963': 0.0, '22963-23089': 0.0, '23089-23215': 0.0, '23215-23341': 0.0, '23341-23467': 0.0, '23467-23593': 0.0, '23593-23719': 0.0, '23719-23845': 0.0, '23845-23971': 0.0, '23971-24097': 0.0, '24097-24223': 0.0, '24223-24349': 0.0, '24349-24475': 0.0, '24475-24601': 0.0, '24601-24727': 0.0, '24727-24853': 0.0, '24853-24979': 0.0, '24979-25105': 0.0, '25105-25231': 0.0, '25231-25357': 0.0, '25357-25483': 0.0, '25483-25609': 0.0, '25609-25735': 0.0, '25735-25861': 0.0, '25861-25987': 0.0, '25987-26113': 1.0, '26113-26239': 1.0, '26239-26365': 0.0, '26365-26491': 2.0, '26491-26617': 5.0, '26617-26743': 5.0, '26743-26869': 5.0, '26869-26995': 12.0, '26995-27121': 19.0, '27121-27247': 7.000000000000001, '27247-27373': 11.0, '27373-27499': 15.0, '27499-27625': 7.000000000000001, '27625-27751': 4.0, '27751-27877': 4.0, '27877-28003': 2.0, '28003-28129': 0.0, '28129-28255': 0.0, '28255-28381': 0.0, '28381-28507': 0.0, '28507-28633': 0.0, '28633-28759': 0.0, '28759-28885': 0.0, '28885-29011': 0.0, '29011-29137': 0.0, '29137-29263': 0.0, '29263-29389': 0.0, '29389-29515': 0.0, '29515-29641': 0.0, '29641-29767': 0.0, '29767-29893': 0.0, '29893-30019': 0.0, '30019-30145': 0.0, '30145-30271': 0.0, '30271-30397': 0.0, '30397-30523': 0.0, '30523-30649': 0.0, '30649-30775': 0.0, '30775-30901': 0.0, '30901-31027': 0.0, '31027-31153': 0.0, '31153-31279': 0.0, '31279-31405': 0.0, '31405-31531': 0.0, '31531-31657': 0.0, '31657-31783': 0.0, '31783-31909': 0.0, '31909-32035': 0.0, '32035-32161': 0.0, '32161-32287': 0.0, '32287-32413': 0.0, '32413-32539': 0.0, '32539-32665': 0.0, '32665-32791': 0.0, '32791-32917': 0.0, '32917-33043': 0.0, '33043-33169': 0.0, '33169-33295': 0.0, '33295-33421': 0.0, '33421-33547': 0.0, '33547-33673': 0.0, '33673-33799': 0.0, '33799-33925': 0.0, '33925-34051': 0.0, '34051-34177': 0.0, '34177-34303': 0.0, '34303-34429': 0.0, '34429-34555': 0.0, '34555-34681': 0.0, '34681-34807': 0.0}}
```

As you can see, the dictionary consists of a range of values in string and their frequency. I would like to plot this as a histogram, but I don't know how I would be able to transform the string into a form that pandas or plotly would understand. What would your approach be? Or is there an easier way to do it, instead of hardcoding things? Or, would another module be easier option in doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A histogram is basically a simple bar chart, where each bar represents a bin (usually in the form of a range) and a frequency of the elements that fall into that bin.

This is exactly the data that you already have. So instead of *computing* values for a histogram (as it would be done with [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)), you can simply pass your data to [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), *as it is*. The result would then be this:

[image: Histogram]

The code with your data, as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scenario_summary = { 'Day1': {
    '22459-22585': 0.0, '22585-22711': 0.0, '22711-22837': 0.0,
    '22837-22963': 0.0, '22963-23089': 0.0, '23089-23215': 0.0,
    '23215-23341': 0.0, '23341-23467': 0.0, '23467-23593': 0.0,
    '23593-23719': 0.0, '23719-23845': 0.0, '23845-23971': 0.0,
    '23971-24097': 0.0, '24097-24223': 0.0, '24223-24349': 0.0,
    '24349-24475': 0.0, '24475-24601': 0.0, '24601-24727': 0.0,
    '24727-24853': 0.0, '24853-24979': 0.0, '24979-25105': 0.0,
    '25105-25231': 0.0, '25231-25357': 0.0, '25357-25483': 0.0,
    '25483-25609': 0.0, '25609-25735': 0.0, '25735-25861': 0.0,
    '25861-25987': 0.0, '25987-26113': 1.0, '26113-26239': 1.0,
    '26239-26365': 0.0, '26365-26491': 2.0, '26491-26617': 5.0,
    '26617-26743': 5.0, '26743-26869': 5.0, '26869-26995': 12.0,
    '26995-27121': 19.0, '27121-27247': 7.0, '27247-27373': 11.0,
    '27373-27499': 15.0, '27499-27625': 7.0, '27625-27751': 4.0,
    '27751-27877': 4.0, '27877-28003': 2.0, '28003-28129': 0.0,
    '28129-28255': 0.0, '28255-28381': 0.0, '28381-28507': 0.0,
    '28507-28633': 0.0, '28633-28759': 0.0, '28759-28885': 0.0,
    '28885-29011': 0.0, '29011-29137': 0.0, '29137-29263': 0.0,
    '29263-29389': 0.0, '29389-29515': 0.0, '29515-29641': 0.0,
    '29641-29767': 0.0, '29767-29893': 0.0, '29893-30019': 0.0,
    '30019-30145': 0.0, '30145-30271': 0.0, '30271-30397': 0.0,
    '30397-30523': 0.0, '30523-30649': 0.0, '30649-30775': 0.0,
    '30775-30901': 0.0, '30901-31027': 0.0, '31027-31153': 0.0,
    '31153-31279': 0.0, '31279-31405': 0.0, '31405-31531': 0.0,
    '31531-31657': 0.0, '31657-31783': 0.0, '31783-31909': 0.0,
    '31909-32035': 0.0, '32035-32161': 0.0, '32161-32287': 0.0,
    '32287-32413': 0.0, '32413-32539': 0.0, '32539-32665': 0.0,
    '32665-32791': 0.0, '32791-32917': 0.0, '32917-33043': 0.0,
    '33043-33169': 0.0, '33169-33295': 0.0, '33295-33421': 0.0,
    '33421-33547': 0.0, '33547-33673': 0.0, '33673-33799': 0.0,
    '33799-33925': 0.0, '33925-34051': 0.0, '34051-34177': 0.0,
    '34177-34303': 0.0, '34303-34429': 0.0, '34429-34555': 0.0,
    '34555-34681': 0.0, '34681-34807': 0.0}}

data = scenario_summary['Day1']

x = range(len(data))
y = list(data.values())

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks(x, data.keys(), rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `bins (ranges)` are already defined and their `counts` are already aggregated at an `initial` level, maybe it can help if you build something that overlays a `histogram (distribution)` on the top of the existing `bin` ranges:

```
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
def plot_hist(bins,input_dict):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(input_dict).reset_index()
    df1['min'] = df1['index'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[0]).astype(int)
    df1['max'] = df1['index'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[1]).astype(int)
    df1['group'] = pd.cut(df1['max'],bins,labels=False)
    df2 = df1.groupby('group' [['Day1','min','max']].agg({'min':'min','max':'max','Day1':'sum'}).reset_index()
    df2['range_new'] = df2['min'].astype(str) + str('-') + df2['max'].astype(str)
    df2.plot(x='range_new',y='Day1',kind='bar')
```

...and call the function by choosing bins lesser than the `length` of the dictionary - or the first level of 98 bins that are already there, like, say if you want a distribution of 20 groups aggregate:

```
plot_hist(20,scenario_summary)
```

**Result Image** :

[image]

hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas module to convert dictionary data into data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scenario_summary = {'Day1': {'22459-22585': 0.0, '22585-22711': 0.0, '22711-22837': 0.0,
                         '22837-22963': 0.0, '22963-23089': 0.0, '23089-23215': 0.0,
                         '23215-23341': 0.0, '23341-23467': 0.0, '23467-23593': 0.0,
                         '23593-23719': 0.0, '23719-23845': 0.0, '23845-23971': 0.0,
                         '23971-24097': 0.0, '24097-24223': 0.0, '24223-24349': 0.0,
                         '24349-24475': 0.0, '24475-24601': 0.0, '24601-24727': 0.0,
                         '24727-24853': 0.0, '24853-24979': 0.0, '24979-25105': 0.0,
                         '25105-25231': 0.0, '25231-25357': 0.0, '25357-25483': 0.0,
                         '25483-25609': 0.0, '25609-25735': 0.0, '25735-25861': 0.0,
                         '25861-25987': 0.0, '25987-26113': 1.0, '26113-26239': 1.0,
                         '26239-26365': 0.0, '26365-26491': 2.0, '26491-26617': 5.0,
                         '26617-26743': 5.0, '26743-26869': 5.0, '26869-26995': 12.0,
                         '26995-27121': 19.0, '27121-27247': 7.000000000000001, '27247-27373': 11.0,
                         '27373-27499': 15.0, '27499-27625': 7.000000000000001, '27625-27751': 4.0,
                         '27751-27877': 4.0, '27877-28003': 2.0, '28003-28129': 0.0,
                         '28129-28255': 0.0, '28255-28381': 0.0, '28381-28507': 0.0,
                         '28507-28633': 0.0, '28633-28759': 0.0, '28759-28885': 0.0,
                         '28885-29011': 0.0, '29011-29137': 0.0, '29137-29263': 0.0,
                         '29263-29389': 0.0, '29389-29515': 0.0, '29515-29641': 0.0,
                         '29641-29767': 0.0, '29767-29893': 0.0, '29893-30019': 0.0,
                         '30019-30145': 0.0, '30145-30271': 0.0, '30271-30397': 0.0,
                         '30397-30523': 0.0, '30523-30649': 0.0, '30649-30775': 0.0,
                         '30775-30901': 0.0, '30901-31027': 0.0, '31027-31153': 0.0,
                         '31153-31279': 0.0, '31279-31405': 0.0, '31405-31531': 0.0,
                         '31531-31657': 0.0, '31657-31783': 0.0, '31783-31909': 0.0,
                         '31909-32035': 0.0, '32035-32161': 0.0, '32161-32287': 0.0,
                         '32287-32413': 0.0, '32413-32539': 0.0, '32539-32665': 0.0,
                         '32665-32791': 0.0, '32791-32917': 0.0, '32917-33043': 0.0,
                         '33043-33169': 0.0, '33169-33295': 0.0, '33295-33421': 0.0,
                         '33421-33547': 0.0, '33547-33673': 0.0, '33673-33799': 0.0,
                         '33799-33925': 0.0, '33925-34051': 0.0, '34051-34177': 0.0,
                         '34177-34303': 0.0, '34303-34429': 0.0, '34429-34555': 0.0,
                         '34555-34681': 0.0, '34681-34807': 0.0}}

# convert to data frame
data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scenario_summary)

# plot data
plt.hist(data_frame['Day1'], density=1, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This creates multiple line graphs though.

Comment: Did you see the x values of the graph? It does not look right

Comment: @Huzo x values are ok [0-19.0]

Comment: They should be the key values of the dictionary. That is, each bin should represent values such as 31909-32035 etc.

Comment: @Huzo then you don't need to use histogram. Histogram shows occurrence of certain range of elements, and normalized this to the largest count value, that in this example is 0.